# What is the simplest way of extracting text from image?

Tags: image-processing, text-extraction

I am a beginner and am confused which method should i use to extract text from image for using it in my project?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the nature of the input image (expected location and font types of the text, size, light conditions, and so on....).

Try [adaptative thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) of image, and then give tesseract-ocr a try on it.

[image]

If you want to dig into details, read this

[interesting paper on TIE (Text information extraction )](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/projects/TextDetectionSurvey.pdf)